# Display table row as list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a table-row as a list, so its better readable on mobile phones. If I use this code:

```
    td {
        display: list-item;
        list-style-type: none;
        width: 50px;
        border: 1px solid silver;
    }
```

It works as should in Firefox and Opera, but not as expected in Chrome and IE. Code on JSfiddle renders as should, in all browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/4J3yw/

Any tricks to solve this?

Comment: `I'm trying to display a table-row as a list` - the two are distinctly different, you shouldnt try to make one do the other as they serve very separate purposes

Comment: What's the unexpected behavior in Chrome and IE?

Comment: The unexpected behaviour is that the td's do not display as as list-item.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments:

`I'm trying to display a table-row as a list` - the two are distinctly different, you shouldnt try to make one do the other as they serve very separate purposes, at the very least what you are attempting to do isnt semantically correct.

What you may look at doing is using a media query to change the nature of your layout, e.g.

(try resizing the viewable space)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4J3yw/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>cell 1</div>
    <div class='cell'>cell 2</div>
    <div class='cell'>cell 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    background:white;
}
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .table, .cell {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats actually what I'm trying; and am hoping I don't need to change the HTML, as it would cost a lot more development and test effort. As for semantics it's a close call wether a list or table would be more appropriate. A div however has no semantic value ;-)

Comment: @Lennart - yes and no, it's relatively neutral vs implying a list is a table or a table a list, not sure it's too pressing a concern though :)

Comment: It's not a pressing concern indeed :-) Main concern is it needs more testing as the site has to work in IE8 too. The table is tried and tested.